# What does the trigger quota of 20 / user / script mean?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, quota

I've been using a script on Google sheets for the past month and it seems to be running fine when manually executed. However, I'd like to add a time trigger to it so that it runs every 30 mins every business day between 6AM and 6PM. Thus, theoretically, the script would be triggered 25 times a day. Given the [quota](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) of 20 / user / script, does this mean that it would run the first 20 times per day only, skipping the last 5? Or does it mean something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the number of triggers that may exist per user, per script, at any one time.

It is not a limit on the number of *executions* those triggers may trigger.

Thus a trigger that runs the script every 30 minutes from 6 to 6 counts as a single Trigger, 1 of the 20 allowed for the user, on the given script.

Rather than a limit the number of total executions per day, you instead are limited in the total amount of Run Time per day via the "Triggers total runtime" limit.

For example, consumer level gmail accounts are limited to 90 minutes of trigger runtime per day. So if your script took 5 minutes to execute each time it was triggered, this type of user could only trigger it 18 times before running out of execution time for the day.

Comment: Adding the link for the quotas: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Comment: `per user, per script`. What does it mean if I'm using one addon with 30 documents and create installable trigger in each of them, there are 30 triggers per user per script. It's a very very realistic scenario. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @kos add-ons operate under different restrictions than stand alone apps script applications.  Although I can't find the documentation, I believe each document in which the add-on is installed would be treated as an individual script, so you wouldn't be limited to 30 documents. However the types and numbers of triggers you may install as an add on is subject to other limits, for example time based triggers are limited to a max frequency of hourly. Unfortunately there is no single "add on trigger restrictions" page that I can find.