# How to manage triggers for a Google Apps Script add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am creating an Editor Addon that let me create automation tasks.

For example I want to be able to create tasks on the model **Trigger-Condition-Action** such as

```bash
When the spreadsheet '123', sheet 'Sheet1', is updated
If Column A equals "Done"
Copy the row to spreadsheet '789' sheet 'Sheet2'
```

##### Problem #1

Because Google imposes quota on the number of triggers I can create,

- For **Time based triggers**, I am thinking storing them on a separate backend and update the sheet via the Sheets API when the time is reached.
- For **Edit triggers**, they can be grouped into a single `onEdit` trigger per spreadsheet. But what if I create an **Edit trigger** on 20+ different spreadsheets?

[Google limitation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) is 20 triggers / user / script.

Does it mean that a user using my addon will be limited to 20 spreadsheets?

##### Problem #2

For the task above, the action should be run only when the condition is met. On every `onEdit`, I need to check for the condition. If I store the user defined tasks on a separate backend, it means I have to call `UrlFetch` inside `onEdit` to check for the condition, which is very inefficient given how often `onEdit` runs.

Is there any best practice to do that without blowing up the `500 KB / property store` quota?

Comment: There are no triggers that support what you are attempting to do.  onEdits only fire on user edits not on changes caused by other scripts or forumulas.  You can use time based forumulas but it's going to be slow having to open lots of spreadsheets and loop through all of their sheets looking for changes in data and you will have to keep a copy of all of the data to be able to detect a change. It doesn't sound like a good idee to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Problem #1

I couldn't find a strong reference but according to the comment from Cameron Roberts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59738867/what-does-the-trigger-quota-of-20-user-script-mean)

> Although I can't find the documentation, I believe each document in which the add-on is installed would be treated as an individual script, so you wouldn't be limited to 30 documents.

##### Problem #2

I will call UrlFetch inside an installable onOpen trigger to retrieve all the tasks of the user. Cache it and test the condition inside onEdit for every edit operation.